# Как проверить наличие определенных символов в url-запросе?

Tags: php

Как удалить из get и post ссылки знаки ------
двойные кавычки - " ",
звездочку *,
знак | и другие символы?
Вот например:

```
http://mysite.ru/htm"""l.html
http://mysite.ru/htm****l
http://mysite.ru/htm||||l
```

Или если есть такой знак, то отправлять на страницу 404.
str_replace, strtr не помогают, и, если можно, код и проверенный ответ.

Comment: [preg_replace()][1] не помогает? И откуда эти символы берутся? Ссылки, наверно, ваш же код генерирует.

   [1]:http://ua2.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match('/\"|\*|\|/', $str)) {
    echo 404;
} else {
    echo 200;
}
```

А вобще это не правильно, так как нужно проверять на допустимые символы в url, а не запрещать таким макаром все подряд, в итоге разбухнуть может регулярка xD

Comment: Мне нужно, чтоб именно эти 3 символы не были, с другими разобрался. А можно код, как проверить на допустимые символы в url, в урле должны быть только латинские буквы, цифры и -. Может, кто-нибудь знает, как будет регулярка? Уже многое время мучаюсь, добрые люди, помогите, плиз.

Comment: @vasak, [такой вариант][1] подойдёт?

   [1]:http://ideone.com/2lnMGu

Answer (score 0):

В нормальных CMS-ках они хватают URL, кидают его в рабочий массив и в дальнейшем с ним работают, как хотят, и офк можно изменять его, как хотите, поэтому никаких проблем, вроде, не должно у вас возникнуть с реализацией данной идеи.